# Round float to 2 decimal places

Tags: c++, rounding

I have a variable Ch1_Data_ThreadShared that is a float with a value like this: 4.50100620731246.

I want to round that number to two decimal places and then save it to a new variable, Ch1_Data_ThreadShared is updated during each iteration of a while loop I have it in and I want to pass the rounded variable to a function. I tried this, but all it does is print the rounded number, not save it.

```
std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << Ch1_Data_ThreadShared;
```

Comment: Multiply it by 100, pass it into [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), and then divide the result by 100.

Comment: You want to save the *rounded* number? If you're computing something you likely don't want to use the rounded number. The current code formats the human output, it doesn't do anything to the number--if you want to modify the number there's `round`.

Comment: Rounding may not save your bacon. 4.50100620731246. may, after everything you do, wind up 4.50000000987. If this is a concern, [fixed point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just pass it to a `ceil` function. Something like this would round it up to two decimal places:

```
#include <cmath>

int roundUp(float toRound) {
    return ceil(toRound * 100) / 100;
}
```

This will return the value rounded up but you can replace `ceil()` with `floor()` to round down.

Comment: Or you can just call `std::round` and get proper rounding.